# How do I manage Larvae in the Campaign maps?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've already noticed that Swarm Queens lack the "Spawn Larvae" ability in the HotS campaign.

Spawning additional larvae is a huge issue when playing Zerg in multiplayer -- what gives? Do I have to build another hatchery if I want more than three Larvae?

Comment: Is it possible the 9 larvae are because of a mission parameter? I haven't seen more than 6 on my playthrough so far. Then again I'm on Brutal. Could the 9 be on an easier difficulty?

Comment: Tested and updated answer.

Comment: Macro hatches is the way to go for sure. Currently about halfway through on Brutal; my first building is generally an expo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hatcheries spawn a different amount of larvae based on your difficulty. 6 on hard and brutal, 9 on casual and normal, rather than 3 larva like in multiplayer. You'll be able to build up more larva with more hatcheries. It is how they managed it in the Starcraft:Brood War days. I'm sure the 300 minerals spent on extra hatcheries is something that is easily affordable in the campaign.

Your other option would be to constantly build units and hope that you have the correct composition. (Which isn't really the zerg way of playing).

Comment: More than only in Brood War. Even in Starcraft II multiplayer, if you want to have more than 10 larvae per minute, you - god forbid - have to build another hatchery.