# Do Queens affect the amount of larva produced in the Heart of Swarm campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

I found it odd that during the campaign, I am unable to use the Queen's ability to spawn larva.  However, it seemed that keeping a queen near my hatchery did cause more larva to spawn.

In the Heart of the Swarm campaign, does keeping a queen near a hatchery affect the amount of larva produced?

Comment: Related [How do I manage Larvae in the Campaign maps?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108387/how-do-i-manage-larvae-in-the-campaign-maps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queens near hatcheries don't cause larvae to spawn, but the difficulty level on the campaign does affect the amount of larvae produced.